# handle many html files with React and Django

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I have a hybrid django+react implementation. Django renders the initial HTML, then react takes control. However, the URLs are managed by Django.

In react, the index.js file is supposed to correspond with one html right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. So, which is the correct approach if I have several HTML files that need react. My index.js file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import { EfestoComponent, WorkTimeComponent, AresComponent } from './components/pulseHome';
import { PulseComponent} from "./components/pulseHistory";

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const efestosData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('efestos-data').textContent);

const efesto = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('efesto'));
const worktime = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('worktime'));
const ares = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('ares'));

const pulse = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('pulse'));


efesto.render(
  <EfestoComponent objects={efestosData}/>
);

worktime.render(
    <WorkTimeComponent/>
)

ares.render(
    <AresComponent/>
)

pulse.render(
    <PulseComponent/>
)
```

As you can see, the efesto, worktime and ares components belong to 1 js file called pulseHome, it holds the components for a file called `pulse_home.html`. Then the pulse component lives in a pulseHistory js file which holds the components for a `pulse_history.html`. When I visit any of the two htmls, it raises the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

of course, since the first elements are not present in the second html, and vice versa. I could solve it with some hacky code (the AI suggests creating another index2.js file), but there must be for a correct and standard approach. I'm kind of new to React. Any advice will help.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest two solutions that may help you here:

1. Use unified element ids on the server while creating your HTML file, as React does. React, by default, looks for the `div` component with the `app` id to render the application. You can use unique sets of ids for generating your HTML files on the server. For example, you must use `efestos-data` id that would make sense to be present in all your HTML files
2. If the first option is not possible for you, you can iterate the initial document to get the dynamic ids and use them to render your React components. Which would be tricky based on how your initial HTML files are generated by the server.

Personally, I think you are using React in the wrong way, maybe you could rethink your whole design and if you need Server Side Rendering and would like to use React as well, maybe consider using [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [What is REST](https://restfulapi.net/) that
says:

> The client-server design pattern enforces the separation of concerns, which helps the client and the server components evolve independently.

Your React application must be responsible for the Front-End part and rendering HTML pages. So having Django doing that for you even a single page is not a gentle way to handle that. You can simply achieve that for everything you may want to do.

Comment: I will accept you other answer since it makes sense. However, the question is still there, what if I have an big app with several complex html pages.

Comment: That's on you and also your framework of choice. Handling them in a proper way depends on the problem, you may want to use server-side rendering or etc.